# Designing a web platform authentication

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, rest, shiro

I have some architecture question when building a complete web platform (a store for example). With consideration with Java, Google App Engine (GAE), Shiro and Restful api's

Consider I have these 3 main components of the platform:

- Front-end UI
- Admin UI
- Backend

These 3 components all run as separate applications in the GAE platform.

**Front-end** ui refers to the UI where 'users' use as the main UI to interact with the system, designed with Javascript and calls into the backend by Javascript

**Admin UI** refers to the UI used by admins to administer the platform, its users and its contents.

**Backend**, is the Restful server/service that both the Front-end UI and Admin-UI connects to, which exposes `/user` api's and `/admin` api's and api that complete the actual logic of the web service provided.

My question would be, where does authentication fits it, if I put the authentication in the backend, how will work with the front-end authentication. Say user logs in by email or by social login (oauth etc.) do I need to provide the Front-end its own authentication then forward to the Backend or in the Front-end this should be just UI and all operation such as login/logout must be through the backend.

If I use Shiro, how can this be achieved. I really prefer that the front-end UI be minimal as possible, of even just be a Single-Page-Application (SPA) or something like that. With this, what should be the binding for both the Front-end UI and the backend (considering they are both different GAE application) in terms of authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this more a proposal and not an answer. I understand that your question is about Java version of GAE, but you can always get inspired by other implementations. [Gae-init](https://github.com/lipis/gae-init) is a web application framework, that demonstrates a majority of good practices. As a contributor I find it distilled knowledge of the last years and an excellent starting point for initializing a large scale web app. I am pretty confident that you will not encounter any problems with Python implementation ;)